# creating a ul li for navigation and blocks wont fit

Tags: css

can some one explain why the box around my links are acting up

code is

**CSS**

```
#navigationbar ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navigationbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
}
#navigationbar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigationbar">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
 <ul>
</div>
```

the box around the links is 19px in height.. the padding makes it 39px, or 41 if i change padding to 11px.. so how do i get it to be 40px like my main navigation container?

or maybe a more efficient way to do all this?

Comment: No opening `div` tag, no closing `li` tag, consider fixing them first

Comment: Sounds like you are letting the font size dictate the height. If precision is important. you should probably set the height and line height of the link to 40px then set the top-padding & bottom-padding to 0.

Comment: Are you using a reset stylesheet?

Comment: @Mr.Alien ok its fixed, do you have a solution? the final height including padding is 39px.

Comment: your anchor tag need to be `display:inline-block` too otherwise the padding won't be added properly

Answer (score 0):

Like this

you use li but forget close li and you do  end tag.

please use `<li></li>` can't use `<li></div>`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7a2u/1/)**

**CSS**

```
#navigationbar ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navigationbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
}
#navigationbar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigationbar">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

---

**[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7a2u/5/)**

**CSS**

```
 #navigationbar ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navigationbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:red;
     height:40px;
}
#navigationbar ul li a {
    padding:11px;
    vertical-align:middle;
```

}

Comment: if you look at your example you will notice that the final size is 39px not 40px.

Comment: @RicardoLara please check demo1 in my answer

Comment: yes i forgot the tags.. but thats not the problem, how do i make the total height of #navigation ul li a{} be 40px.. even in your answer its still 39px

Comment: @RicardoLara i will again changes in my answer please demo1 now its 40px;

Comment: now in demo1 the height is 41px... how do i get it to be 40px?

Comment: @Ricardo Lara in padding 11px remove and add 10px; now u got 40px; may be

Comment: or maybe 10px padding on top and 11px padding on bottom? to make it total 40px.. i think ill try that

Comment: closing ul should be </ul> not <ul>

Answer (score 0):

**Try this css the height of anchor is 40px now ,**

**CSS**

```
    #navigationbar ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navigationbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 19px;
}
#navigationbar ul li a {
    padding: 10px 0px 11px 0px;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigationbar">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is not the tags...(yes theyre missing in the example) but my question is how do i get the height of the links to be 40px?

Comment: closing ul should be </ul> not <ul>

Comment: #navigationbar ul li a {
    padding: 10px 0px 11px 0px;

} //This will give 40px height to your anchor

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div id="navigationbar">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
 <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: <li> end tag </li> cant use this <li></div> it was wrong please delete your answer or  other wise changes in your answer.

Comment: he just copied and pasted my question into an answer.. trying to increase post count?

Comment: sorry its paste by mistake, i have edited this answer, sorry and thanks for alert me.